# Shutdown spring application from ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to close the context from an ApplicationListener?

```
   public class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
            // on some certain condition we want to shutdown spring ie close the context
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)event.getApplicationContext()).close();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that Spring still wants to finish the startup process here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
```

And therefore throws an IllegalStateException:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@dcb84c98
>   has been closed already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems likely that the question you actually wanted to ask is "How do I interrupt Spring-Boot startup".

Throw an exception from your `onApplicationEvent` method.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that you want to **interrupt** Spring on startup.

Simple you will not able to do that with out getting error.

If you will still like to kill your application while startup just use:

```
System.exit(0);
```

But if you want to close the context after the initial you can listen to a different [`Spring event`](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2) called `ApplicationReadyEvent`

```
@Component
public class MyListener {

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) throws Exception {
        event.getApplicationContext().close();
    }
}
```

> ApplicationReadyEvent -  Event published as late as conceivably possible to indicate that the application is
>    * ready to service requests