# How to do a simple "failable" main in springboot with @autowired?

Tags: java, spring-boot, program-entry-point

I'd like to do a simple main using Spring boot and have some fields autowired.

I'd like the app to fail (error-code != 0) if some exception is thrown in the process.

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SqlInserterMain
{
    @Autowired
    private static JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SqlInserterMain.class, args);

        insertData();

        context.close();
    }

    private static void insertData()
    {
        // Do something with jdbcTemplate.
        // If jdbcTemplate fails on exception, the app should fail and return some error code.
        System.out.println("YOYO" + jdbcTemplate);
    }
}
```

But, `jdbcTemplate` is null.

If I add a `@component` or an `ApplicationRunner`, the `@autowire` will work but I won't get the main to fail.

Any idea how to do a fast and simple main with some autowired fields that will fail on an exception? Thanks.

Comment: I think the best way to do that would be to create an simple Bean with the dependencies that are needed....

Comment: Why did you add `static` to `JdbcTemplate`?

Comment: I added `static` because I want to access it from `main`, which is also `static`.

Comment: see similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399924/spring-boot-autowired-in-main-class-is-getting-null

Comment: @user7294900 - When an exception thrown in a `@PostConstruct` method, will it fail the `main` as well?

Comment: @user7294900 - I don't see a `Configuration` nor a `Component` class in my question.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` is `@Configuration` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

Comment: @user7294900 - Any idea how to implement it without `@Configuration`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to [execute code on startup](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-execute-on-startup/)

You can use `ApplicationListener` and auto wire `JdbcTemplate` or beans you need to execute task

```
@Component
@Order(0)
class MyApplicationListener 
    implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("YOYO" + jdbcTemplate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the the whole app stop and return and error code if an exception is thrown in the `ApplicationListener`?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka if you throw an exception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837551/shutdown-spring-application-from-applicationlistener

Comment: I tested this and it partly works. When an exception was thrown, the app indeed stopped but the error code was `0` :(

Comment: what error code do you mean? process exit code? this solution is the cleanest for sure!

Comment: Yes, the app (process) returned exit code 0 even though an exception occurred and haven't been caught be my code. I'd like spring boot to fail with an exit code `1` - just like a regular java main.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka You can use `ExitCodeExceptionMapper` https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-exit-codes

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I manually wired the bean, caught the exception, printed the exception and exit myself (`close()` or `System.exit(1)`) :(

I wish spring-boot had some way to behave like a normal java main.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SqlInserterMain
{
    private static JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SqlInserterMain.class, args);

        try
        {
            jdbcTemplate = context.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);

            insertData();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        context.close();
    }

    private static void insertData()
    {
        // Do something with jdbcTemplate.
        // If jdbcTemplate fails on exception, the app should fail and return some error code.
        System.out.println("YOYO" + jdbcTemplate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `SqlInserterMain` is considered to be a bean managed by Spring (well, it's not instantiated by Spring, is it?). Just create an additional bean (as yAzou mentioned) or manually extract the JdbcTemplate from the Spring context.

Comment: I eventually did `jdbcTemplate = context.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);` but I was wondering if there's a way to do this using `@Autowired`.

Comment: There is a way to do it using @Autowired: Put it in another class and make it non-static.

Comment: @Taschi - How do you instantiate that other class?

Comment: You do not. Annotate it with @Component, and Spring will instantiate it for you.

Comment: @Taschi - As required by the question, will it fail the whole main on exception?

Comment: If Spring Boot tries and fails to autowire something, your application will always exit with rc != 0, so yes. In your case, Spring Boot does not even try because you use @Autowired in a context where it is not actually allowed. I suggest reading up on how Spring CDI actually works.

Comment: @Taschi - An exception can be thrown in the code logic, regardless of the `@Autowired`. I'd like the whole spring application to fail if my code have thrown an exception.

Comment: If you use Spring Batch, it'll generally do that if there's an error inside a batch step.

Comment: How about manually calling `System.exit(foo);` or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown in case of errors (in the exception catch block)?